# 2to3 doesn't exist and can't install the script on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

Currently I'm running python3 with version 3.6.5. Unfortunately I've encountered a Python file that has a lot of python2 in it and I want to simply convert everything to python3. I keep seeing this package called 2to3 online, but it simply just doesn't exist on my computer.

Here's part of the Python documentation that mentions 2to3: https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

Unfortunately, whenever I run `locate Tools/scripts` in my Terminal I get nothing. There isn't even a PyPI package for 2to3. What's the best way for me to obtain this 2to3 script?

NOTE: I'm using the zsh shell, but this probably shouldn't matter.

Comment: Just type `2to3` on the command line.

Comment: That's the issue. The command 2to3 doesnt exist.

Comment: `2to3` should be in the same directory as your `python` binary it is distributed with python. What OS are you on?

Comment: Make sure you run 2to3 on the shell command line, not python command line.

Comment: I'm on Linux Ubuntu 18.04. I've looked in the binaries but didn't find the scripts at all. I'm also running 2to3 in the terminal and not through the interpreter.

Comment: What does `which 2to3` say?

Comment: says 2to3 not found

Comment: The reason it's not on PyPI is that it comes as part of the Python standard library. Many Linux distros strip out parts of the standard library into separate packages—but you have to install those separate packages with `apt-get`, not `pip`. For example, you might have to `sudo apt-get python3-2to3` or `sudo apt-get python3-examples`. (At one point, Debian put `2to3` in its `python-examples` package, but I don't know if Debian/Ubuntu still does that.)

Comment: You can use your favorite dpkg search tools or websites to find which package is the right one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newer debian distributions (ubuntu included) no longer include `2to3` (and subsequently `lib2to3`) as part of the default installation of `python3`.

It has been split into a separate package which can be installed as follows:

```
sudo apt install 2to3
```

Answer (score 3):

`2to3` is installed in the same folder as python.

if by typing  2to3 you get `command not found` try as follows.

```
which python --> to get the python executable path (in my case `/Users/newbie/bin/python`)
```

and then check if exists with

```
ls /Users/newbie/bin | grep 2to3
```

If it's the case you can just create an alias

Comment: Hmm actually I may be able to set an alias to /usr/bin/2to3-2.7 and that may be able to fix my issue.

Comment: Fixed by setting the alias. Thank you!

Comment: @DJPoland This is going to run the version of `2to3` that came with Python 2.7, not the one that came with Python 3.6. I think that won't be a problem today, but in a year and a half, when they stop backporting changes to 2.7, it might be. (On the other hand, they might also just stop updating 2to3, in which case you'd be fine.)

Comment: When you run 2to3, you ought to review the changes (with a diff tool) and test your scripts in 3 to confirm.  If your scripts are not overly voluminous, or contain too many version specific points of syntax, it shouldn't matter if you are running a 2to3 conversion that is relatively old.  Those discrepancies are more likely "fringe cases", and/or things to be manually ironed out.